# Arduino not forming Bluetooth connection/sending sensordata from arduino to android

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, android-sensors, arduino-ide

I'm using arduino Mega ADK and RedBear BLE shield. 
The goal is to make arduino send sensordata to androidphone(nexus 7) via bluetooth. Sensor should be accelerometer/Gyro type.

I have used RedBears SimpleChat as a starting point to get understanding how this is suppose to work, but i'm having some problems. When i use RedBears own app from google play store and the examples that they distribute, everything works just fine. App finds arduino and i can connect to it that way.
But i can't connect to arduino without the app, it just... rejects it. I have tried changing my tablet settings anyway possible but that just doesn't seem possible.

Additionaly if i run any other code(not from the redbear i mean) to arduino, tablet cant find arduino from bluetooth connections anymore and neither can any app that has BT finding properties.

So what i'm trying to figure out is:

- A way to connect my tablet to arduino without redBear app.
- Does the redBear BLE shield somehow prevent other codes to be passable?
- Does the redBear have some kind of BT method that is better than others?

Any help, examples or answers are much appreciated.
Sorry for the bad English -_-

Comment: "But i can't connect to arduino without the app, it just... rejects it"-what and how are you trying to connect to the arduino without the app.

Comment: because you use BLE? you need a proper interface to communicated between the board and the phone. BLE is not like regular Bluetooth, it does not work as a serial port.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a SDK provided by RedBearLab for Android https://github.com/RedBearLab/Android. It also contains examples.